Distribution of non-linear combination of random variables
Suppose $P, Q, R, S$ are uniformly random independent real numbers in $(0,1)$.
I want to find an expression for the the distribution of the random variable $Y = \frac{4R^2 + 4S^2 - P^2 - Q^2}{8S - 4\max(P,Q)}$
Or perhaps easier than finding an expression for the distribution - I want to find $\Pr[a \le Y \le b]$ for constants $a,b$.
Context: this comes from a geometry problem about whether two randomly chosen points in a square satisfy a certain property.
I have tried solving this computationally using standard library random number generators, but I’m concerned this method yields systematically incorrect (due to the use of floating point numbers) and imprecise results (given a reasonable amounts of computing time and resources).
Are there some techniques or pointers for this?

Please explain the context behind this question, and what techniques you have already tried.

@mathperson314 updated the question

There may be an easier way to solve your original problem, perhaps by symmetry arguments, instead of trying to compute that probability. Can you share the original problem?

what are the possible values of $Y?$ Do you assune $P,Q,R,S$ independent? If it is the case then the densities of the independent rv $A=R^2+(S-y)^2$ and  $B=P^2+Q^2-4y \max(P,Q)$ are painfully explicit and you can express $\Pr(Y<y)=\Pr(4A-4y^2<B)$ with only one integral (I doubt that the last one is computable)

@LetacGérard thanks, this looks promising! P, Q, R, S are indeed independent. what did you mean by “I doubt that last one is computable”?

I mean the integral equal to $\Pr(4A-4y^2<B.)$ By the way, have you found the smallest interval where $Y$ takes its values?
